# Why does my document change size between Illustrator and Inkscape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, svg, workflow

If I create a 150mm x 150mm document in Illustrator, as such:

[image]

and then create a 80mm x 80mm square in the middle of the document, as such:

[image]

then save to .svg format, when I open the document in Inkscape, the document size is this:

[image]

and the square size is this:

[image]

### Why does this happen, and how can I fix this issue to have a precise workflow?

Comment: The problem is with Illustrator's default 72ppi.  The CSS standard is 96ppi (which Inkscape abides by).  See this related question with possible work arounds: [Change Illustrators native SVG resolution](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128038/change-illustrators-native-svg-resolution)

Comment: @BillyKerr Why would the CSS standard be 96ppi? That's so random... I am making real-life objects and I need to see them at 100% on my screen... Maybe I can export to another format that Inkscape would open in the right size?

Comment: Did you try the workaround I posted in the other question. It's really quite simple - only a small manual edit of the XML. Another option is to use PDF as the transfer format between the two applications.

Comment: 96ppi was not a random choice. It was the Windows standard ppi, and Mac was 72ppi (back in the day), but more people use PCs than Macs, so they changed it. Adobe resisted the change and continued to use 72ppi as the default. Of course nowadays, most modern computer monitors and mobile devices have even higher resolution display, so it's a kind of historical legacy anyway. And of course since SVGs are vector, the ppi doesn't really matter, except in specific cases such as yours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of the other question - which is not precisely the same, but is about the same issue, and has suggested fixes, and gives reasons for the problem.  If anybody objects feel free to vote to re-open.

Comment: @BillyKerr when I was looking for a similar question I couldn’t find because of wording of the older question. My question might get more search hits since it’s worded differently? Idk