# Illustrator resizing vectors in SVG on Export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg

I have a grouping of vectors I am trying to export as an SVG. The problem is Illustrator keeps resizing the export. What starts as a width of ~18.5 inches in illustrator, is now ~13.6 inches when I open the SVG in any other program. Why would it be doing this? and How can I preserve the original vector size?

This occurs whether I export by artboard or not, using either Export As or Export for Screens, or either 3 of the SVG styling options.

Comment: See this [related question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128038/change-illustrators-native-svg-resolution/129918#129918) for solutions. It's essentially a problem Adobe is aware of, but hasn't fixed.

Comment: @BillyKerr essentially adobe has with strong words said that it will not fix this. When the svg consortium was debating this they would do this Adobe say that they would not be able to comply with a fixed rule or make all old adobe illustrator files obsolete. So adobe basically told svg consortium were you to do this they would basically never comply. Basically a fixed coversion factor between physical units is a bat shit crazy idea that should not have been even suggested. This kind problems is what you get from such thinking! Shame css consortium and shame Adobe.

Comment: @joojaa - but couldn't they just fix it for SVG output/import, or at least make it an option? It all seems a bit petty if you ask me. Yes, it's an absolute shame.

Comment: @BillyKerr yes but now adobe users would no-longer be able to design SVG files in pixels. Given that on screen rendering is what SVG is about, its not really suited for anything else. There is no way out of this other than disallowing pixels to be units, no other solution will fix more problems than it generates. And its not like we didn't know this before they did this decisions. This is a well know issue in science.

Comment: @BillyKerr That's how Inkscape handled switching from 90 to 96dpi and it pretty much hasn't been a problem since. This is 100% an Adobe issue.

Comment: Also, @joojaa CSS and SVG are heavily interlinked and CSS is primarily a web standard. Having pixels fixed to a standard dpi makes perfect sense from a web-developer's view and was definitely the right decision. It would be an absolute nightmare to design websites with widely varying dpi across mobile devices. Web-developers usually want similarly sized elements on different devices and it would be infinitely more complex if you had to take every possible screen's physical dpi into account.

Comment: @Xrott thats not what im saying. What im saying is if you want to design in physical units design in physical units if you want to design in pixels design in pixels. Having ppi wouldnt affect browsers in any way they would render pixels. The problem is that having fixed conversion presupposes that nobody else hasa fixed definition for a pixel, which infact adobe and many systems do. So now your standard is forcing other competing standards to crash. Pixels have no inherent size so coercing a fixed size will fail in many cases since its essentially unnatural for the object.

Comment: Also considering that adobe is in fact one of the biggest platform this is also a svg problem for adoption into physical manufacturing. We could sidestep problems with getbers, dxf and pdf. Also note that inkscape does support having random ppi conversion factor set. Unlike svg standard. Anyway what im saying is its essentially wrong to do something thats unnatural to the data since it affect others too, just because its okay to you does not mean its okay. Simply because of this i can never know of the svg has right size on laser printer or not.

Comment: Though to be honest im not really personally in favor of having pixels as units at all. I would be much happier with a logical unit like design pixel or something and then having a templating mechanism that says size in different contexts.

Comment: @joojaa Historically websites were designed with pixel-based units on screens that had all similar dpi. Only with the rise of mobile devices did a bigger range of physical dpi start to appear on the web. The W3C is very much about not breaking old existing websites, so a button with 48px height should be about the same physical size on all devices regardless of the actual dpi of the screen. That is what a standard is for – so that all compatible systems produce predictable output. Compatibility with other standards, especially for things *outside the primary scope* is not a priority.

Comment: Also, it is important to note that the SVG 1.1 standard was released in the early 2000s and the slightly more recent SVG 2.0 specification has been in limbo for countless years, so the standard has been pretty much left untouched for a very long time. The issue with dpi and pixel-units in question is inside the CSS standard (not SVG), which again is primarily a web- and screen-only technology. Print and physical media is not their main priority, so Adobe is *not* a major platform for them. That would be Google (Chrome), Apple (Safari), Microsoft (formerly with IE), and other browser vendors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138566/discussion-between-joojaa-and-xrott).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah this is most likely caused by the difference in definition of pixel size. Back when the SVG consortium floated the idea that a fixed size pixel should have the size 98 pixels per inch, adobe objected and said that the svg should have a specifier how to scale pixels. SVG went with fixed size, to use same system as css. Adobe declined to implement as per their explanation they would do so.

98/72* ~13.6= ~18.5

maths certainly checks out.

Not much you can do about this high level politics.